# No action javascript on load page

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I load my page, the js must display a default value : month,
The problem is the graphic is not displayed.
I must click on month to display the information.

In my ajax, console query string : `range: month` and this code to identified the range.

```
  $group = HTML::sanitize($_GET['range']);

  if (empty($group)) {
    $group = 'month';
  }

 switch($group) {
 }
```

Below the javascript code (plot libray) allowing to display the graphic

Thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#range a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().parent().find('li').removeClass('active');

    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '{$link}?range=' + $(this).attr('href'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            if (typeof json['order'] == 'undefined') { return false; }

            var option = {  
                shadowSize: 0,
                colors: ['#9FD5F1', '#1065D2'],
                bars: { 
                    show: true,
                    fill: true,
                    lineWidth: 1
                },
                grid: {
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    hoverable: true
                },
                points: {
                    show: false
                },
                xaxis: {
                    show: true,
                    ticks: json['xaxis']
                }
            }

            $.plot('#chart-sale', [json['order'], json['customer']], option);   

            $('#chart-sale').bind('plothover', function(event, pos, item) {
                $('.tooltip').remove();

                if (item) {
                    $('<div id="tooltip" class="tooltip top in"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">' + item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2) + '</div></div>').prependTo('body');

                    $('#tooltip').css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        left: item.pageX - ($('#tooltip').outerWidth() / 2),
                        top: item.pageY - $('#tooltip').outerHeight(),
                        pointer: 'cusror'
                    }).fadeIn('slow');  

                    $('#chart-sale').css('cursor', 'pointer');      
                } else {
                    $('#chart-sale').css('cursor', 'auto');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

$('#range .active a').trigger('click');
</script>
```

error console :

```
uncaught TypeError: $.plot is not a function
    at Object.success (index.php:280)
    at c (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:2)
```

line :

```
        $.plot('#chart-sale', [json['order'], json['customer']], option);
```

Comment: it seems to be syntax error with <!-- and //--> in your script. remove it and try again.

Comment: Make and code updated : It seems this line has a problem :  $.plot('#chart-sale', [json['order'], json['customer']], option);

Comment: what errors did you have in console tab?

Comment: @ducmai uncaught TypeError: $.plot is not a function ==> see above.

Comment: so it is clear that you need to add your plot plugin before your code :). or if you already have that on right place then maybe jquery conflict version

Comment: @ducmai I have other graphics with the same libray, I have no problem, no error. When I click on my dropdown about this graphic, I have no error. The error is produced only when the page is loaded

Comment: Try to wrap all the code into your script inside `$(document).ready(function(){ <your_code> })`

Comment: Anyway make sure the jquery.flot's script is after the jquery script and before your script. If you're using a cdn make also sure that the link is available and it's running fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write the answer just to close the post (you can see the discussion in the question comments)
Remember that JavaScript is not compiled so every expression is read top-bottom. To make sure your functions are recognized by the interpreter you need to give the right order to your scripts.
Anyway you could execute your code after the page has been loaded by `windows.load = function(){<your_code>}` in JavaScript or `$(document).ready(function(){<your_code>})` if you’re using jQuery library .